# How to do string manipulation in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know I'm close to figuring this out but need a little help. What I'm trying to do is all grab a column from a particular table, but chop off the first 4 characters. For example if in a column the value is "KPIT08L", the result I was is 08L. Here is what I have so far but not getting the desired results.

```
 SELECT LEFT(FIELD_NAME, 4)
 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, [`left`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/left.php) will give you the leftmost characters. If you want the characters starting at a specific location, you need to look into [`mid`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/mid.php):

```
select mid (field_name,5) ...
```

Secondly, if you value performance,portability and scalability at all, this sort of "sub-column" manipulation should generally be avoided. It's usually far easier (and faster) to patch columns together than to split them apart.

In other words, keep the first four characters in their own column and the rest in a separate column, and do your selects on the relevant one. If you're using anything less than a full column, then it's technically not *one* attribute of the row.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
SELECT MID(FIELD_NAME, 5)  FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Mid is very powerfull, it let you select the starting point and all the remainder, or,
if specified, the length desidered as in

```
SELECT MID(FIELD_NAME, 5, 2)  FROM TABLE_NAME  ' gives 08 in your example text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(FIELD_NAME,LEN(FIELD_NAME)-4)
 FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

If it is for a generic string then the above one will work...

Comment: This of course assumes the strings will have 7 characters, which might not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have Access at my current location, but please try this.

```
SELECT RIGHT(FIELD_NAME, LEN(FIELD_NAME)-4)
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Seems a roundabout way to use `mid()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT(FIELD_NAME, 4) will return the first 4 caracters of FIELD_NAME.

What you need to do is :

```
 SELECT MID(FIELD_NAME, 5)
 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

If you have a FIELD_NAME of 10 caracters, the function will return the 6 last caracters (chopping the first 4)!